How to modify an emacs window frame title from the command line to manage multiple servers and clients?
I am trying to setup a few different emacs servers on my system for different activities like emails, org, programming.
I found the --set-frame-parameters should take care of it, but I have not been able to figure out how to make it work. I found a few examples of window geometry, and tried to build from there, but I keep getting syntax errors. One working example I based my attempts on: emacsclient -s editor -cn -F "((fullscreen . maximized))"
This parameter, also named -F seems to take an elisp list as an argument. I tried multiple variants of the following: emacsclient -s editor -cn -F "((frame-title-format . ('Emacs Editor')))".
Reading the doc, I thought that frame parameters like name or title might be more suitable for what I am trying to achieve, but nothing works.
I would be grateful if someone knew how to make it work, or had any input as to how to manage multiple servers and clients. I thought the setup I was going for was pretty basic, but seeing how few examples I foud on the net, I am starting to wonder if I am not missing something here.
Thanks for your time.

Most people don't run multiple emacsen, they connect to a single emacs with multiple invocations of emacsclient. emacsclient -cn -F '((title . "foo"))' works fine for me here.

Thanks, it actually works for me too. I must be really tired, it must be one of the 'variants' I tried. I feel a bit dumb; thanks for pointing that out. Your comment was actually helpful for my multiple servers setup too. In my previous testing, all client instances attached to a particular socket, were simply mirroring each other. After your comments, I tested again, and I managed to get independent client instances on the same server. That makes more sense now to have only one server running. Thanks again. I definitely need some time off my screen !
